# Outputting object in Python using print

Tags: python, class

I am instantiating a class and simply want to dump the object using print.  When I do this I seem to get some sort of object id.  Can't I just issue a "print ObjectName" and the result would just be the attributes of the object?  Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color, make, model):
        self.color = color
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

    def getAll():
        return (self.color, self.make, self.model)


mycar = Car("white","Honda","Civic")
print mycar
```

When I run this I get the following result:

```
<__main__.Car instance at 0x2b650357be60>
```

I would expect to see the color,make,model values as well.  I know if I print them individually via:

```
print mycar.color,mycar.make,mycar.model
```

It output:

```
white Honda Civic
```

Just as I would expect.  Why does "print mycar" output an instance id and not the attribute values?

Comment: One note to the question of asking why doesn't Python, by default, print the attribute values: what happens if one of your attributes was something more complicated, such as a connection to a database? How would it print that out? Also, what happens if your car had 120 different attributes (or, probably better, something like a dictionary of the features of a car). Should the ENTIRE list of features get printed? The default in Python, while typically not helpful, is pretty safe, and doesn't assume anything about your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a [`.__str__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) on your class. It'll be called when printing your custom class instances:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color, make, model):
        self.color = color
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join((self.color, self.make, self.model))
```

Demo:

```
>>> mycar = Car("white","Honda","Civic")
>>> print mycar
white Honda Civic
```

In addition, you could implement a [`.__repr__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) too, to provide a debugger-friendly representation of your instances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `__str__` and `__repr__` to get "friendly" values for your class objects.

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for more details on this.

`__repr__` is the official string represntation of an object and is called by `repr()` and `__str__` is the informal string representation and is called by `str()`